# Is it good to build library or API using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently building a library or API which will be used by another Spring REST application, below are the advantages I thought of using Spring.

1. Spring flow(Context initialization->Post construct)
2. Easy way of reading properties file
3. Autowiring and bean management
4. Rapid development

Below are the disadvantage

1. Tightly coupled, the main application which is going to use the library/API has to import or refer the configuration class of library in order to initialize context
2. Main application has to use Spring(considering use in other projects)

Is there anything I am missing, can Spring framework be used to develop API or library?

Note: The number of library to build is 3-5 and will grow in future.

Comment: Quite a subjective question, but broadly speaking - yes, using a dependency injection framework has many advantages. Dont worry too much about the configuration class - it's only used for creating the bean context, it's not related to the funcational requirements of your application nor detrimental to its architecture in any way

Comment: Most of the APIs that are available, depend on one or more libraries (even Spring). That is one of the reasons why, when a dependency is pulled, it pulls other dependencies with it. So, in my view, the answer is YES

Comment: It really depends on what API or library actually do. And if you're really need Spring for this. One big disadvantage are dependencies. If develop your library using Spring 5 and I want to use it in my app which is build with Spring 4, will it be compatible? Who knows. Will I need to update to Spring 5 just to use your library? If yes, I will really have to balance advantages of using your library vs. costs of upgrade to the next Spring version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason to use spring you are giving, is to benefit from the building of the application runtime.

I do not see it as a great advantage from spring for a library : it is only replacing a few `new` and `set` statements, that could be easily explained in a doc, with even some sample bean declaration for the users of your api, if he wishes to init your lib in a spring context.

One of the drawback you are not giving is the support of multiple versions of spring by your library :
what will happen in one / two years, when an old application developped using your library will need small enhancements, but still be on spring v4, but new application will import spring v6 (with no resource to migrate old app on spring v4 to latest version) ?

So i would use spring in a library only if you need to participate in database transaction of the main application (and other tasks like this where it is really convenient to use spring), but otherwise try to depend as little as possible on spring.

EDIT:
Even when minimising the use of spring in the runtime of your library, you can use it extensively to test your library.

The spring context instead of being included in the resource of your lib is only a test resource, which you can use to bootstrap spring-test, for example.